# How can count the number of rows meeting a time condition in bash?

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, terminal

I have a txt file with 1000 rows of various epoch times (1396848990 = Sun Apr  6 22:36:30 PDT 2014). How can I count the number of rows taking place between 8 PM and midnight.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Also include your best attempt to solve your problem, StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and **free code** are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to do the following:

```
awk 'int(strftime("%H", $1)) >= 20 {print $1}' $input_file | wc -l
```

It will use `strftime()` to convert unix epoch time stamps to hours (`%H`), cast it to an integer (`int()`) and compare to the number 20. If the number is larger - print the time stamp.

On the outside, `wc` can take care of counting the lines printed.

Of course, you can count with `awk`, too:

```
awk 'int(strftime("%H", $1)) >= 20 {n+=1} END{print n}' $input_file
```

It will silently initialize the variable `n` with zero and print the result at the end.

**Edit**: strftime() seems to [exist in GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html):

```
$ awk -V
GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)
```

Comment: I don't think strftime exists in unix... I'm getting an error:
awk: calling undefined function strftime
 input record number 1, file times.txt
 source line number 1
       0

Comment: Maybe you need to call `gawk` on your machine instead? Are you running on MacOS? It probably doesn't have GNU awk by default.

Answer (score 0):

While `awk` surely is faster and easier to read, I think you can do this using only (modern) `bash`.

Something like this should work:

```
let counter=0; (while read -ra epoch; \ 
do [ $(printf "%(%H)T" ${epoch[0]}) -ge 20 ] && \ 
let "counter++"; done; echo $counter) <inputfile
```

It works like Pavels answer but with bash's printf to format the date (probably still `strftime` behind the curtains). 
`read`ing to an array (`-a`) and `let counter++` only works in modern bash (4?)

Answer (score 0):

If your `date` command supports -d (--date) option, how about:

```
from=$(date +%s -d "Apr 6 20:00:00 PDT 2014")
to=$(date +%s -d "Apr 7 0:00:00 PDT 2014")
awk -v from=$from -v to=$to '$0 >= from && $0 <= to' file | wc -l
```